# Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-styles

I am trying to use [this ProgressWheel librery](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel), but I am facing this error after run the proyect.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@theme value=(@style/AppTheme) from AndroidManifest.xml:11:9-40   is also
> >     present at [com.github.Todd-Davies:ProgressWheel:1.2]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:13:9-56 value=(@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar).
> >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to 
> >     element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-23:19 to override.

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.anda.soft.apppresentation">

    <application
        android:name=".di.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

and my style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Any idea about how to solve it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Any idea about how to solve it?

Follow the instructions that were given to you in the error message:

> Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:theme"' to element at AndroidManifest.xml:5:5-23:19 to override.

In other words, add `tools:replace="android:theme"` to your `<application>` element.

Or, switch to a different library.

Comment: Yes I am going to switch to a different library , I am facing another issue now .

Comment: Isn't there any other alternative?

Comment: @SlickSlime: Why is adding `tools:replace="android:theme"` in the manifest a problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare it seems that tools:replace="android:theme" at the application level changes the look of themed UI elements in libraries. Is that expected?  If so, that's a problem.  Any way to work around that?  It seems strange that manifest attributes in libraries don't get their own namespace during manifest merging...

Comment: @CCJ: "Is that expected?" -- yes. I mean, the point of `tools:replace` is to replace something coming from a library. "Any way to work around that?" -- don't use `tools:replace` and live with the theme from the library. Or, don't use the library. Or, talk to the library developers and see what recommendations they have. Having an `android:theme` attribute on an `<application>` element *in a library* might be valid in specific scenarios (e.g., a framework that drives the whole UI), but on the whole it seems like it should be a code smell.

Answer (score 9):

https://github.com/sawankumarbundelkhandi/edge_detection/issues/12#issuecomment-669854455

After a lot of searching, I found this solution working, actually, he did the same as the other told to add

Add these two lines `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"` and `tools:replace="android:theme"` to the `application` tag

Also, add this line `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the root manifest tag too

Here is the full code

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.doitcare.app"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application
        tools:replace="android:theme"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        ...>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```